# eslint: error Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved but I cannot use ES6

Tags: node.js, eslint

So I recently added eslint to my projects with the following configuration:

```
var OFF = 0, WARN = 1, ERROR = 2;

module.exports = exports = {

    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "amd": true,
        "node": true,
    },

    "extends": "eslint:recommended",

    "rules": {
        // Possible Errors (overrides from recommended set)
        "no-extra-parens": ERROR,
        "no-unexpected-multiline": ERROR,
        // All JSDoc comments must be valid
        "valid-jsdoc": [ ERROR, {
            "requireReturn": false,
            "requireReturnDescription": false,
            "requireParamDescription": true,
            "prefer": {
                "return": "returns"
            }
        }],

        // Best Practices

        // Allowed a getter without setter, but all setters require getters
        "accessor-pairs": [ ERROR, {
            "getWithoutSet": false,
            "setWithoutGet": true
        }],
        "block-scoped-var": WARN,
        "consistent-return": ERROR,
        "curly": ERROR,
        "default-case": WARN,
        // the dot goes with the property when doing multiline
        "dot-location": [ WARN, "property" ],
        "dot-notation": WARN,
        "eqeqeq": [ ERROR, "smart" ],
        "guard-for-in": WARN,
        "no-alert": ERROR,
        "no-caller": ERROR,
        "no-case-declarations": WARN,
        "no-div-regex": WARN,
        "no-else-return": WARN,
        "no-empty-label": WARN,
        "no-empty-pattern": WARN,
        "no-eq-null": WARN,
        "no-eval": ERROR,
        "no-extend-native": ERROR,
        "no-extra-bind": WARN,
        "no-floating-decimal": WARN,
        "no-implicit-coercion": [ WARN, {
            "boolean": true,
            "number": true,
            "string": true
        }],
        "no-implied-eval": ERROR,
        "no-invalid-this": ERROR,
        "no-iterator": ERROR,
        "no-labels": WARN,
        "no-lone-blocks": WARN,
        "no-loop-func": ERROR,
        "no-magic-numbers": WARN,
        "no-multi-spaces": ERROR,
        "no-multi-str": WARN,
        "no-native-reassign": ERROR,
        "no-new-func": ERROR,
        "no-new-wrappers": ERROR,
        "no-new": ERROR,
        "no-octal-escape": ERROR,
        "no-param-reassign": ERROR,
        "no-process-env": WARN,
        "no-proto": ERROR,
        "no-redeclare": ERROR,
        "no-return-assign": ERROR,
        "no-script-url": ERROR,
        "no-self-compare": ERROR,
        "no-throw-literal": ERROR,
        "no-unused-expressions": ERROR,
        "no-useless-call": ERROR,
        "no-useless-concat": ERROR,
        "no-void": WARN,
        // Produce warnings when something is commented as TODO or FIXME
        "no-warning-comments": [ WARN, {
            "terms": [ "TODO", "FIXME" ],
            "location": "start"
        }],
        "no-with": WARN,
        "radix": WARN,
        "vars-on-top": ERROR,
        // Enforces the style of wrapped functions
        "wrap-iife": [ ERROR, "outside" ],
        "yoda": ERROR,

        // Strict Mode - for ES6, never use strict.
        "strict": [ ERROR, "never" ],

        // Variables
        "init-declarations": [ ERROR, "always" ],
        "no-catch-shadow": WARN,
        "no-delete-var": ERROR,
        "no-label-var": ERROR,
        "no-shadow-restricted-names": ERROR,
        "no-shadow": WARN,
        // We require all vars to be initialized (see init-declarations)
        // If we NEED a var to be initialized to undefined, it needs to be explicit
        "no-undef-init": OFF,
        "no-undef": ERROR,
        "no-undefined": OFF,
        "no-unused-vars": WARN,
        // Disallow hoisting - let & const don't allow hoisting anyhow
        "no-use-before-define": ERROR,

        // Node.js and CommonJS
        "callback-return": [ WARN, [ "callback", "next" ]],
        "global-require": ERROR,
        "handle-callback-err": WARN,
        "no-mixed-requires": WARN,
        "no-new-require": ERROR,
        // Use path.concat instead
        "no-path-concat": ERROR,
        "no-process-exit": ERROR,
        "no-restricted-modules": OFF,
        "no-sync": WARN,

        // ECMAScript 6 support
        "arrow-body-style": [ ERROR, "always" ],
        "arrow-parens": [ ERROR, "always" ],
        "arrow-spacing": [ ERROR, { "before": true, "after": true }],
        "constructor-super": ERROR,
        "generator-star-spacing": [ ERROR, "before" ],
        "no-arrow-condition": ERROR,
        "no-class-assign": ERROR,
        "no-const-assign": ERROR,
        "no-dupe-class-members": ERROR,
        "no-this-before-super": ERROR,
        "no-var": WARN,
        "object-shorthand": [ WARN, "never" ],
        "prefer-arrow-callback": WARN,
        "prefer-spread": WARN,
        "prefer-template": WARN,
        "require-yield": ERROR,

        // Stylistic - everything here is a warning because of style.
        "array-bracket-spacing": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "block-spacing": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "brace-style": [ WARN, "1tbs", { "allowSingleLine": false } ],
        "camelcase": WARN,
        "comma-spacing": [ WARN, { "before": false, "after": true } ],
        "comma-style": [ WARN, "last" ],
        "computed-property-spacing": [ WARN, "never" ],
        "consistent-this": [ WARN, "self" ],
        "eol-last": WARN,
        "func-names": WARN,
        "func-style": [ WARN, "declaration" ],
        "id-length": [ WARN, { "min": 2, "max": 32 } ],
        "indent": [ WARN, 4 ],
        "jsx-quotes": [ WARN, "prefer-double" ],
        "linebreak-style": [ WARN, "unix" ],
        "lines-around-comment": [ WARN, { "beforeBlockComment": true } ],
        "max-depth": [ WARN, 8 ],
        "max-len": [ WARN, 132 ],
        "max-nested-callbacks": [ WARN, 8 ],
        "max-params": [ WARN, 8 ],
        "new-cap": WARN,
        "new-parens": WARN,
        "no-array-constructor": WARN,
        "no-bitwise": OFF,
        "no-continue": OFF,
        "no-inline-comments": OFF,
        "no-lonely-if": WARN,
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": WARN,
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": WARN,
        "no-negated-condition": OFF,
        "no-nested-ternary": WARN,
        "no-new-object": WARN,
        "no-plusplus": OFF,
        "no-spaced-func": WARN,
        "no-ternary": OFF,
        "no-trailing-spaces": WARN,
        "no-underscore-dangle": WARN,
        "no-unneeded-ternary": WARN,
        "object-curly-spacing": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "one-var": OFF,
        "operator-assignment": [ WARN, "never" ],
        "operator-linebreak": [ WARN, "after" ],
        "padded-blocks": [ WARN, "never" ],
        "quote-props": [ WARN, "consistent-as-needed" ],
        "quotes": [ WARN, "single" ],
        //"require-jsdoc": [ WARN, {
        //    "require": {
        //        "FunctionDeclaration": true,
        //        "MethodDefinition": true,
        //        "ClassDeclaration": false
        //    }
        //}],
        "semi-spacing": [ WARN, { "before": false, "after": true }],
        "semi": [ ERROR, "always" ],
        "sort-vars": OFF,
        "space-after-keywords": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "space-before-blocks": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "space-before-function-paren": [ WARN, "never" ],
        "space-before-keywords": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "space-in-parens": [ WARN, "never" ],
        "space-infix-ops": [ WARN, { "int32Hint": true } ],
        "space-return-throw-case": ERROR,
        "space-unary-ops": ERROR,
        "spaced-comment": [ WARN, "always" ],
        "wrap-regex": WARN
    }
};
```

After fixing my issues, I now only have some errors remaining on my consts.

```
eslint: error Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved but I cannot use ES6
```

The recognized fix seems to be to enforce ES6. My application runs on AWS Lambda Node 12 and it doesn't work with the ES6 syntax because then I get

```
"errorMessage": "Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/lambda.js\nrequire() of ES modules is not supported.\nrequire() of /var/task/lambda.js from /var/runtime/UserFunction.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains \"type\": \"module\" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.\nInstead rename lambda.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove \"type\": \"module\" from /var/task/package.json.\n",
"code": "ERR_REQUIRE_ESM",
```

How can I fix this? Can I ignore the const rule somehow?

Comment: `Unexpected token import` is because Node doesn't directly support `import`, not because Node doesn't support ES6.

Comment: Did it works without eslint?

Comment: The code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },

    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

Trying adding this in your `.eslintrc.json`

Comment: I tried it. However now I got a bunch of new erros, for example that module isn't defined, require is not defined. Also Const is still red but now shows a lot of rule's replacements.

Comment: Also I don't think I should use ES6 at all. I tried that syntax before but lambda does not support it.

Comment: I per my knowledge, the const keyword was introduced in es6 and if you are using that along with eslint then you need to mention es6 or above in .eslintrc config. Maybe the problem is with the way you are using lambda.
Do you have tried to replicate this issue without any lambda?